# How to simplify exponential of a matrix into Cosine and Sine Hyperbolic terms?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

In Peskin and Schroeder book "An Introduction to QFT" there is an equation (eq. 3.48):

[image]

I know that exp(x)=cosh(x)+sinh(x). But, I couldn't understand how the above equation is obtained. Any help is welcome.

Also why is the above matrix chosen for boost from four momentum (m,0) to (E,p^3)?

Comment: Hint: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2n}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Taylor expansion of an exponent and even and odd powers of the matrix under the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to consider the series: for any function $f$ of any variable $x$ (scalar, vector, matrix, operator...) taking its value in any vector space, you always have the even/odd decomposition:
$$f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+ \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}.$$
If $f$ is the exponential function, the first term on the right hand side above is called $\cosh$ and the second term is called $\sinh$.